# Event Bus and Asynchronism in receptors execution

Tags: multithreading, performance, memory, optimization

I challenged myself to design and implement (in Java, but still at the design level) of an Event Bus, for multithreading. There is no serious usage of this system planned in the future, the only interest is in the challenge itself and its optimization.

Event Bus were designed in order to have asynchronous execution between the firing of the event and the code associated to its reception. However, with a thread (EventManager) controlling the  event bus, I see two possible implementation.

My question is: **Which one if this two implementations is the best?**

**1)** The EventManager thread calls each systems subscribed to the event and run its code in a sequential way.
Although this solutions is indeed asynchronous when thinking about emitter - receptors, we still have a synchronism during the execution of multiple receptors. Also, if one of the receptor function takes time, we have a delay in the entire execution of the bus management.

**2)** Each receptor system has its own buffer bus, and the EventManager thread only retransmits the event to the subscribed systems, multiplying the memory used (event may be rewritten in multiple systems at the same time) but resolving the synchronism problem.

I guess in a typical system (ie game, non computing-heavy software or time critical solution), the first one is the best. The second might take a lot of memory for not that much time optimization.

Did you have this problem before? Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between the two, you need to pick and choose what your design requirements need.

For option 1:

**Pros:**

- Sequential designs are (in my experience) easier to design and implement
- Easier to control and understand (in that you can implement even priorities as a side effect of sequence)
- Mutation of your event passed between each receptors do not need synchronization because it is thread-confined.

**Cons:**

- Again as you discussed, if one receptor blocks, the other receptors in line will suffer.
- As a result of sequentiality, receptors will not be able to take advantage of parallel computing.

For option 2:

**Pros:**

- Receptors operate independently of each other (and provide more opportunity for parallelization)
- As long as events are processed as soon as it reaches the buffer, memory is not really adversely affected
- Receptors that block can use the buffer to store events for later processing instead of holding up the line

**Cons:**

- Receptors must be well coordinated in order to implement things such as event priorities and ensuring that all receptors (even those that block and have the event enqueued) finish together
- Mutating the event requires clients submitting receptors to use synchronization in order to remain data consistent with other receptors

If anything, I would personally take option #2 in favor of performance because often memory will suffer as a side effect of performance gain. However if your target audience does not develop multithreaded clients or synchronization is hard to enforce, I would go with option #1 in preference with safety and reliability.

Comment: EDIT I meant option #1 in my second scenario in the conclusion, my bad.